# Google script revision history is too short - is there a way to retrieve further back

Tags: google-apps-script, recovery, google-apps-script-editor

I have probably overwritten a google sheet's script file by having it open simultaneously on two remote computes.
I am looking at the script's revision history, but it only goes back to a half day. Is there a way to go further back in time to the version I had saved yesterday?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "version I had saved". Is this a named code version (you have to try to create these). Or is this just the result of pressing the "Save" button after writing some code?

Comment: Just the result of pressing the Save button. Not saved through the version save feature

Comment: Start using a third party and a real dev environment. With Apps Script, you can use [`clasp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) + version control

Comment: I tried clasp but I was only able to see the full Project saved versions. Is there a way to view a longer revision history through clasp?

Comment: The idea is that you would have version control for the intermediate "non-Version" saves, e.g. you commit early and you commit often.

Comment: Makes sense. I will set that up going forward. But for now does this mean there is no way to retrieve what I lost yesterday?

Comment: Pretty much. The Apps Script editor is not at all collaborator friendly (which is a huge departure from other Google projects, especially Sheets and Docs. If anyone else is viewing the script, you might as well stop making changes because you can't see what they do, and they can't see what you do, until they reload their entire webpage.

Comment: You are probably right. It just seems like a lot of extra little steps each time I want to save... (add, commit, push..).. not to mention: I might just forget to do it. Why can't it just *work*.

Comment: It's easy to download an Apps Script file.  In Google Drive, right click the file and choose download.  It downloads as a .json file.